# Can't install add-ons for Firefox on newly installed Lubuntu 17.04

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, plugins

I installed Lubuntu for the first time yesterday and since then I'm unable to access the Firefox Add-ons website properly. The site takes a very long time to load and then I only get the html without the CSS. I can find some add-on and try to install it but again it fails to download.

Every other website that I've tried is working just fine. I tried chromium as well and it works perfectly with extensions.

I haven't installed Flash or restricted extras, just the base system.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about the url: "about:addons" ?

Comment: No, I mean https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/

For now it seems to be the only url on the internet that doesn't work...